# Same Label displayed for Multiple Data Sets? (MatPlotLib, Python 3.9)

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.9

Is it possible to assign data sets to existing data labels with MatPlotLib?

Even if the data sets are assigned the same label name & color, in the actual resulting plot, in the legend they are separate, and have different colors. I'm using Python 3.9.

Let's say we have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataX = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
dataY = [[0, 1, 2], [2, 1, 0]]

dataLabel = "Test Data"

for i in range(len(dataX)):
    plt.plot(dataX[i], dataY[i], label = dataLabel)

plt.legend(loc = 'best')

plt.show()

plt.close()
```

This results in the following plot:
[image]

And what I want is for both of these data lines to be the same color, and have them both be labeled as the same "Test Data" label instance.

Is what I'm trying to achieve here even possible with MatPlotLib?

Thanks for reading my post, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a color:

```
color = 'blue'
```

Set this color in `plot` function. Set label to first line only.

```
line = plt.plot(dataX[0], dataY[0], label=dataLabel, c=color)
for i in range(1, len(dataX)):
    plt.plot(dataX[i], dataY[i], c=color)

plt.legend(loc='best', handles=[line[0]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply;
That could be a workaround for the color, however there are still 2 separate data labels for "Test Data"... I would like to combine those as well. Any further ideas?

Comment: New code added.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This works and appears to be sufficent for my application, I want to ask you a further question regarding this solution, just to make sure I 100% understand it:
When you reference "line[0]", you are referencing the first data instance, and consequently it's label, correct?

Comment: I'm referencing the line ploted by `dataX[0], dataY[0]` above `for` loop, and consequently it's label.... Every `plot` returns a list with lines plotted...

Comment: Alright, thanks. Would I also however be able to do this with a scatter plot? If I try to take a variable from a "plt.scatter()", and try to read the first index from that variable, I get a "PathCollection object is not subscriptable" error. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind... I realized that for some reason, when you call the "scatter()" function instead of the "plot()", it doesn't make the resulting variable a list. It works for me with a scatter plot if I just reference "line" instead of "line[0]".

Comment: It's correct. The `plt.scatter` function returns a `PathCollection` object.